# Numpy tensor indexing

Tags: python, numpy

I'm a little bit new to Python & Numpy, but I've noticed that when you call operator `[]` on a numpy array `A`, if it's a single index that is used (e.g., `A[1]`), the resulting sub-array is 1 dimension smaller, but if it's a range of indices (e.g., `A[1:]`) the dimension of the subarray remains unchanged, even if the range of indices covers only a single index, e.g., in this above case, if `A` was `2x2`, `A[1:]` is effectively just a single index, but the resulting size is not the same as `A[1]`.

My question is: is this always true in that if you supply a range of indices when extracting a subarray, the dimension doesn't change, and that a single index always reduces the dimension by 1? Are there edge cases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is always the case. When you use *one* index-value, e.g. `A[1]`, you are effectively saying "give me the subarray `A[1]`", which, by definition, has a dimensionality smaller (by 1).

When you request a range of indices, e.g., `A[1:]` you are  "cropping" `A`, to get everything *but* the first slice (`A[0]`). See, the *range of indices* define the axis you "lost" in the previous case (`A[1]`).

The following docs should be helpful to understand numpy arrays (indexing):

- Arrays: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/absolute_beginners.html#more-information-about-arrays
- Indexing: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.indexing.html

Comment: Do you know where I can find documentation on how the slicing operators work internally? I also have some other questions beyond my OP, such as using multiple sets of brackets instead of commas, e.g., `A[1][2][3]` vs `A[1,2,3]`. I think I have a general idea of how it all works, but just wanted to consult some formal documentation rather than experimenting all the time

Comment: multiple sets are applied sequentially.  Have you looked up indexing in the official numpy docs?

Comment: @student010101 I updated my answer to what I think you should read to have a good understanding not only on indexing but the arrays themselves.